# Notepad++ regex - search only in certain column all numbers between two numbers?

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

i have now 250 million lines of text from a database.

I want to highlight only certain values, that are only in the third column.
I use this `\b1011(3[1-9]\d[1-9]|[4]\d\d\d|5[0-8][0-3][0-6])\b` for highlight all values between 10113101 to 10115836.
Can one exclude the numbers from column 4?

Edit: a column means for me the text between the spaces

> ```
> 1           2        3      4     5  ..... columns
> 307607 1317011864 10113101 -25 13135611 2700 0 0 0 12 0 0 0 walk029h.rwx
> 2264 910115836 10114632 -15 20111192 900 0 0 0 11 0 0 0 walk029.rwx
> 326169 1010523891 10115836 -1 20911192 0 0 0 0 11 0 0 0 walk12h.rwx
> 38718 826265392 10113628 0 10114603 2700 0 0 0 11 0 0 0 street2.rwx
> 241512 1317011864 636346 0 10113987 900 0 0 0 12 0 0 0 walk029h.rwx
> 38718 826266129 10113448 0 10114310 900 0 0 0 10 0 0 0 tree5m.rwx
> 38718 826266243 10113898 0 10114810 900 0 0 0 10 0 0 0 tree9m.rwx
> ```

Comment: What is your expected output for the input given? Is it 690, 995, 6325, etc (the 3rd column?). What do you mean exclude numbers in column 4? Like since 345 is in column 4, don't match it if it shows on column 3?

Comment: If I search with my regex then the numbers between 10113101 to 10115836 are also highlighted in column 4, but I just want to highlight the numbers only in column 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This pattern](https://regex101.com/r/ekemsW/9) will capture the numbers you want in the third column only. Refer to capture group 1 for their values.

`^(?:\S+\s){2}\b(1011(?:3[1-9]\d{2}|4\d{3}|5[0-8][0-3][0-6]))\b.*`

All I did was modify yours to add the prefix and removed some redundancy.

Comment: I have test it, but 10113500 it was overlooked, for example in the red box [link](http://optest.kodash3d.de/stackoverflow/fgjsfhsfh.jpg)

Comment: Because your original pattern didn't allow for that as a valid option. I've updated my answer to allow that number.

Comment: hmm column 3 is highlighted correctly, but in the one line column 4 is included which is not wanted. Example in the green box on my [>picture<](http://optest.kodash3d.de/stackoverflow/dghkgjh.jpg).
But I am glad that I come closer to my result I thank you :)

Comment: You should be able to fix that by putting `^` at the beginning of your pattern. I'll update again.